# How to write this do...while from C++ to Python?

Tags: python, c++

How to write this do...while from C++ to Python??

I looked at a lot of topics, but I don’t understand how to write with such functionality

```
do

     { L = 0; x = a; h = h / 2;  

       while (x < b) {

           y1 = fC(x);

           y2 = fC(x+h);

           L = L + sqrt(h * h + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1)); 

           x = x + h;

       }

       L = L * 2;

    }

while (fabs(L0 - L) / L0 > 0.0001);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:  # do --> while True:
   L = 0 
   x = a
   h = h / 2
   while x < b:
       y1 = fC(x)
       y2 = fC(x+h)
       L = L + sqrt(h * h + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1)) 
       x = x + h
   L = L * 2
   if fabs(L0 - L) / L0 > 0.0001: break # do's while --> if ... : break
```